# Выделение поясняющих оборотов при помощи тире

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли здесь выделять определительный оборот "как внешними, так и внутренними" тире с двух сторон, или это будет неправильно и достаточно только одного тире, которое, в свою очередь, как бы заменяет собой запятую?

Но, как показывает практика, для выстраивания клиентоориентированных взаимодействий как характеристики бизнеса, отражающей стремление и умение компании налаживать комфортные взаимовыгодные отношения со своими клиентами — как внешними, так и внутренними, этого может быть недостаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно одного тире, так как это не вставка, а обособленное определение внутри другого обособленного оборота.

В устной речи это определение интонационно не выделяется, встраивается в интонационную схему предложения

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере нужно одно тире. Т.к. - это обособленное определение, стоящее в конце предложения.

Определения, стоящие в конце предложения, как нераспространенные, так и с зависимыми словами, могут отделяться знаком тире. Такие определения имеют пояснительно-уточняющее значение.

См.: Академический справочник.

Answer (score 0):

Либо скобки, либо две запятые, либо два тире. Это именно *вставка*

Comment: А как тогда закрыть причастный оборот "отражающей..."?

Comment: А почему это "именно вставка", как вы определили?

Comment: Или вот, например: Мой вопрос, сделанный — я это мог видеть — не вовремя, раздражил ее.
Если построить предложение, как у нас: Мой вопрос, сделанный не вовремя — я это мог видеть, раздражил ее. Или все же: Мой вопрос, сделанный не вовремя — я это мог видеть — раздражил ее.

Comment: Только здесь это действительно вставка, вводное предложение, а там она выступает в роли определения.

Comment: При вставки обязательное условие: предложение должно прерываться: здесь предложение не прерывается, а с помощью тире выделяется  уточняющие определение.

Comment: Alenka, в обоих случаях - "вставка", вставная конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь действительно надо ограничиться одним тире, но мотивация другая. Второе, закрывающее тире просто "поглощает" запятая, так сказать "более высокого уровня". Если слово "поглощает" не нравится, это можно сформулировать так. Внутри обособленной конструкции (оборота, отдельного предложения), имеющего собственные внешние знаки, парное тире в начале и конце такой внешней конструкции опускается. Мотивация обособления при этом не важна.

Я называю это "принципом матрешки". Точно так же запятая не ставится перед закрывающими кавычками, скобками, точками и проч.

Единственный знак, который всегда ставится независимо от структуры фразы - скобка.

И, кстати, скобки очень наглядно показывают, что здесь именно уточнение, вводная конструкция, обособленное определение, а не просто "определение" как член предложения. Парные тире всегда ставятся там и только там, где можно поставить скобки (разница между этими двумя знаками в том, что скобки используются для более оторванной от обшей линии повествования вставки, но в общем-то знаки взаимозаменяемы.